# Layered Border - is this possible to do in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, border, java-7

Folks,

I have read several threads on stackoverflow and googled some(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) and asked around all Swing experts at work before deciding to post a question.  I have basic understanding of Swing and this complicates things terribly.

[image: http://i58.tinypic.com/f1fo1w.jpg]

I have attached a picture of a button...this is a button with nearly 3 borders (as much my eyes can tell). The rectangle on the right is the Digital Colormeter application on a Mac. The mouse is sitting between the black border and the grayish border that you see on the button image.

Based on what we see on the pixelated image of the border, it appears the border has a tail or a shadow that covers many pixels. Take the Blac for instance, it has atleast 3 pixels(internal border). The external border is grayish - and it spans nearly 6 pixels.

Here is what I have done:
   I experiemented with several versions of Strokes and with BasicStroke(3.0F), I could produce 2 pixels of information for both the intenal and external border.

Here is my question:
1. Is such a "high touch" rendering possible using Swing in Java 7?
2. If so, can you please point me in the right direction?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create compound borders and stack them

```
class GUI extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new GUI();
    }

    GUI() {

        Border[] borders = new Border[]{
                   BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN, 3, true),
                   BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 3, true),
                   BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY, 6, true)};
        Border border = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(borders[2], 
                        BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(borders[1], borders[0]));
        JButton button = new JButton("Button");
        button.setBorder(border);

        add(button);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

---

**Edit1 - Stacking `LineBorder`s**

Here are many examples of creating gradients by stacking line borders. The code is long because of the amount of examples, you can just copy the `private` methods. There are over 3000 single `Border` components in the final view and I don't notice any performance issues.

```
class GUI extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new GUI();
    }

    public GUI() {

        JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
        JButton button;
        Border b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6;

        button = new JButton("Button");
        button.setBorder(compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.BLACK, Color.GREEN, 5)));
        tabs.addTab("Black-Green 5", button);

        button = new JButton("Button");
        button.setBorder(compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.BLACK, Color.GREEN, 100)));
        tabs.addTab("Black-Green 100", button);

        button = new JButton("Button");
        button.setBorder(compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.BLACK, Color.GREEN, 200)));
        tabs.addTab("Black-Green 200", button);

        button = new JButton("Button");
        button.setBorder(compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.GREEN, Color.BLACK, 5)));
        tabs.addTab("Green-Black 5", button);

        button = new JButton("Button");
        button.setBorder(compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.GREEN, Color.BLACK, 100)));
        tabs.addTab("Green-Black 100", button);

        button = new JButton("Button");
        button.setBorder(compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.GREEN, Color.BLACK, 200)));
        tabs.addTab("Green-Black 200", button);

        button = new JButton("Button");
        b1 = compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.GREEN, Color.BLACK, 5));
        b2 = compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.BLACK, Color.GRAY, 5));
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(b2, b1));
        tabs.add("Green-Black-Gray 5", button);

        button = new JButton("Button");
        b1 = compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.GREEN, Color.BLACK, 50));
        b2 = compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.BLACK, Color.GRAY, 50));
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(b2, b1));
        tabs.add("Green-Black-Gray 50", button);

        button = new JButton("Button");
        b1 = compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.GREEN, Color.BLACK, 100));
        b2 = compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.BLACK, Color.GRAY, 100));
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(b2, b1));
        tabs.add("Green-Black-Gray 100", button);

        button = new JButton("Button");
        b1 = compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, 50));
        b2 = compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.BLUE, Color.RED, 50));
        b3 = compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, 50));
        button.setBorder(compoundBorder(new Border[] {b1, b2, b3}));
        tabs.add("Green-Blue-Red-Green 50", button);

        button = new JButton("Button");
        b1 = compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, 50));
        b2 = compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.BLUE, Color.RED, 50));
        b3 = compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, 50));
        button.setBorder(compoundBorder(new Border[] {b3, b2, b1}));
        tabs.add("{Green, Blue, Red} 50", button);

        button = new JButton("Button");
        b1 = compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.MAGENTA, Color.BLUE, 2));
        b2 = compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, 2));
        b3 = compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.CYAN, Color.GREEN, 2));
        b4 = compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW, 2));
        b5 = compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.YELLOW, Color.ORANGE, 2));
        b6 = compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.ORANGE, Color.RED, 2));
        button.setBorder(compoundBorder(new Border[] {b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6}));
        tabs.add("Rainbow 2", button);

        button = new JButton("Button");
        b1 = compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.MAGENTA, Color.BLUE, 20));
        b2 = compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, 20));
        b3 = compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.CYAN, Color.GREEN, 20));
        b4 = compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW, 20));
        b5 = compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.YELLOW, Color.ORANGE, 20));
        b6 = compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.ORANGE, Color.RED, 20));
        button.setBorder(compoundBorder(new Border[] {b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6}));
        tabs.add("Rainbow 20", button);

        button = new JButton("Button");
        b1 = compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.MAGENTA, Color.BLUE, 40));
        b2 = compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, 30));
        b3 = compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.CYAN, Color.GREEN, 15));
        b4 = compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW, 15));
        b5 = compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.YELLOW, Color.ORANGE, 30));
        b6 = compoundBorder(interpolateColors(Color.ORANGE, Color.RED, 40));
        button.setBorder(compoundBorder(new Border[] {b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6}));
        tabs.add("Rainbow assymetric", button);

        add(tabs);
        pack();
        setSize(new Dimension(1000, 600));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private static Color[] interpolateColors(Color c1, Color c2, int width) {

        Color[] colors = new Color[width];
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            colors[i] = new Color( (c2.getRed() - c1.getRed()) / width * i + c1.getRed(),
                                  (c2.getGreen() - c1.getGreen()) / width * i + c1.getGreen(),
                                  (c2.getBlue() - c1.getBlue()) / width * i + c1.getBlue() );
        }
        return colors;
    }

    private static Border compoundBorder(Color[] colors) {

        Border b = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(colors[0], 1, true);
        for (int i = 1; i < colors.length; i++)
            b = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(colors[i], 1, true), b);
        return b;
    }

    private static Border compoundBorder(Border[] borders) {

        Border b = borders[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < borders.length; i++)
            b = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(borders[i], b);
        return b;
    }
}
```

---

**Edit2 - Single `StrokeBorder`**

Since the gradients can be radial or linear, you can't get a rectangular-symmetric border, but you can still get some nice results. To make good use of these you have to read [RadialGradientPaint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/RadialGradientPaint.html) and [LinearGradientPaint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/LinearGradientPaint.html).

While you need only one border for this, there is a lot of setup to be done beforehand. Also, since the border is a graphics object and not a Swing object, it won't resize with the components is surrounds. The only way I can think of for really having a symmetrical border is to paint a rectangle (with Java2D) and tie it to the component's bounds such that it surrounds it through resizing. In any case, this can surely be useful in the right hands, but here are some examples.

```
class GUI extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new GUI();
    }

    public GUI() {

        JTabbedPane mainTabs = new JTabbedPane();
        JTabbedPane linTabs = new JTabbedPane();
        JTabbedPane radTabs = new JTabbedPane();
        JButton button;
        Point2D start, end;
        float[] dist;
        Color[] colors;
        BasicStroke stroke;

        start = new Point2D.Float(0, 0);
        end = new Point2D.Float(500, 500);
        dist = new float[] {0.0f, 0.2f, 1.0f};
        colors = new Color[] {Color.RED, Color.WHITE, Color.BLUE};
        LinearGradientPaint lgp;
        stroke = new BasicStroke(5);
/// Linear ///
        button = new JButton("Button");
        lgp = new LinearGradientPaint(start, end, dist, colors);
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createStrokeBorder(stroke, lgp));
        linTabs.addTab("Red-White-Blue 5", button);

        button = new JButton("Button");
        end = new Point2D.Float(200, 200);
        lgp = new LinearGradientPaint(start, end, dist, colors, CycleMethod.REFLECT);
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createStrokeBorder(stroke, lgp));
        linTabs.addTab("Red-White-Blue Reflect 5", button);

        button = new JButton("Button");
        end = new Point2D.Float(500, 500);
        lgp = new LinearGradientPaint(start, end, dist, colors, CycleMethod.REPEAT);
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createStrokeBorder(stroke, lgp));
        linTabs.addTab("Red-White-Blue Repeat 5", button);

        stroke = new BasicStroke(20);
        button = new JButton("Button");
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createStrokeBorder(stroke, lgp));
        linTabs.addTab("Red-White-Blue 20", button);

        button = new JButton("Button");
        end = new Point2D.Float(200, 200);
        lgp = new LinearGradientPaint(start, end, dist, colors, CycleMethod.REFLECT);
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createStrokeBorder(stroke, lgp));
        linTabs.addTab("Red-White-Blue Reflect 20", button);

        button = new JButton("Button");
        end = new Point2D.Float(500, 500);
        lgp = new LinearGradientPaint(start, end, dist, colors, CycleMethod.REPEAT);
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createStrokeBorder(stroke, lgp));
        linTabs.addTab("Red-White-Blue Repeat 20", button);

        dist = new float[] {0.0f, 0.2f, 0.4f, 0.6f, 0.8f, 1f};
        colors = new Color[] {Color.RED, Color.ORANGE, Color.YELLOW, Color.LIGHT_GRAY,
                                Color.BLACK, Color.RED};
        stroke = new BasicStroke(5);

        button = new JButton("Button");
        lgp = new LinearGradientPaint(start, end, dist, colors);
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createStrokeBorder(stroke, lgp));
        linTabs.addTab("Dark 5", button);

        button = new JButton("Button");
        end = new Point2D.Float(200, 200);
        lgp = new LinearGradientPaint(start, end, dist, colors, CycleMethod.REFLECT);
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createStrokeBorder(stroke, lgp));
        linTabs.addTab("Dark Reflect 5", button);

        button = new JButton("Button");
        end = new Point2D.Float(500, 500);
        lgp = new LinearGradientPaint(start, end, dist, colors, CycleMethod.REPEAT);
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createStrokeBorder(stroke, lgp));
        linTabs.addTab("Dark Repeat 5", button);

        stroke = new BasicStroke(20);
        button = new JButton("Button");
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createStrokeBorder(stroke, lgp));
        linTabs.addTab("Dark 20", button);

        button = new JButton("Button");
        end = new Point2D.Float(200, 200);
        lgp = new LinearGradientPaint(start, end, dist, colors, CycleMethod.REFLECT);
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createStrokeBorder(stroke, lgp));
        linTabs.addTab("Dark Reflect 20", button);

        button = new JButton("Button");
        end = new Point2D.Float(500, 500);
        lgp = new LinearGradientPaint(start, end, dist, colors, CycleMethod.REPEAT);
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createStrokeBorder(stroke, lgp));
        linTabs.addTab("Dark Repeat 20", button);
/// Radial ///
        Point2D center = new Point2D.Float(20, 20);
        float radius = 1;
        dist = new float[] {0.0f, 0.2f, 1.0f};
        colors = new Color[] {Color.RED, Color.WHITE, Color.BLUE};
        RadialGradientPaint  rgp;
        stroke = new BasicStroke(40);

        button = new JButton("Button");
        rgp = new RadialGradientPaint(center, radius, dist, colors, CycleMethod.REPEAT);
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createStrokeBorder(stroke, rgp));
        radTabs.addTab("{Red, Blue White} assymetric 40", button);

        button = new JButton("Button");
        radius = 300;
        stroke = new BasicStroke(10);
        center = new Point2D.Float(500, 250);
        rgp = new RadialGradientPaint(center, radius, dist, colors, CycleMethod.REPEAT);
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createStrokeBorder(stroke, rgp));
        radTabs.addTab("{Red, Blue White} REPEAT 40", button);

        button = new JButton("Button");
        radius = 150;
        rgp = new RadialGradientPaint(center, radius, dist, colors, CycleMethod.REFLECT);
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createStrokeBorder(stroke, rgp));
        radTabs.addTab("{Red, Blue White} Reflect 40", button);

        colors = new Color[] {Color.PINK, Color.MAGENTA, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, Color.GREEN, Color.PINK};
        dist = new float[] {0.0f, 0.2f, 0.4f, 0.6f, 0.8f, 1f};

        button = new JButton("Button");
        radius = 70;
        Point2D focus = new Point2D.Float(40, 90);
        rgp = new RadialGradientPaint(center, radius, focus, dist, colors, CycleMethod.REFLECT);
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createStrokeBorder(stroke, rgp));
        radTabs.addTab("Light Reflect assymetric", button);

        button = new JButton("Button");
        rgp = new RadialGradientPaint(center, radius, focus, dist, colors, CycleMethod.REPEAT);
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createStrokeBorder(stroke, rgp));
        radTabs.addTab("Light Repeat assymetric", button);

        button = new JButton("Button");
        radius = 70;
        stroke = new BasicStroke(10);
        center = new Point2D.Float(500, 250);
        rgp = new RadialGradientPaint(center, radius, dist, colors, CycleMethod.REFLECT);
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createStrokeBorder(stroke, rgp));
        radTabs.addTab("Light Reflect 10", button);

        button = new JButton("Button");
        stroke = new BasicStroke(10);
        center = new Point2D.Float(500, 250);
        rgp = new RadialGradientPaint(center, radius, dist, colors, CycleMethod.REPEAT);
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createStrokeBorder(stroke, rgp));
        radTabs.addTab("Light Repeat 10", button);

        mainTabs.addTab("Linear", linTabs);
        mainTabs.addTab("Radial", radTabs);
        add(mainTabs);
        pack();
        setSize(new Dimension(1000, 600));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comments and ideas are welcome.

Comment: Thank you - I considered this earlier when looking at LineBorders, but does line borders help create a gradient for the borders?  For example, the Gray color alone has the following gradient (240,240,240), (165,165,165), (133,133,133), (221,221,221) and (246,246,246) - that is a total of 5 pixels for the Gray Border alone. I am somewhat confused by your last sentence - are you suggesting do it pixel by pixel and be done with it OR for each LineBorder, we can create a gradient...can you please suggest how gradients for Borders is achieved...that is what I am looking for. Thank you

Comment: You have 2 ways to do it: (1) "Pixel by pixel" by specifying many LineBorders of different widths and colors. It's actually not as bad as it looks because you can procedurally generate the colors of a gradient, say (165,165,165 - 5*x) where x is the border number and then combining them. (2) Using Java2D to create a border with gradients built into it. This means all you need is 1 border, but Java2D is annoying in my opinion. I will try to edit my answer with examples for both. Which to choose will probably depend on the complexity of the final border.

Comment: This is very clear & thank you for helping with the examples. I will read up given I know it can be done :-). If performance and rendering speed is important - does option 2 not cut it? What is the impact if I decided to use option 1 and draw nearly 12-18 borders for every button on the screen. I may have as much as 10-12 buttons on the GUI screen (heavy user-touch application, like a point of sale application)

Comment: In terms of performance as long as you don't go into many hundreds, possibly thousands, I don't think there is any issue. In term of rendering speed, unless you update (redraw \ repaint etc.) the GUI very frequently (many times per second I'd guess) there won't be an issue since you can cache all the borders in memory and not recreate them. Option 2 will probably be more efficient, but hard to say. I'll test the numbers and put my money where my mouth is.

Comment: Thank you - I need a little more direction please. I am using Java2D and hence option2 is a natural choice. Wrt Option 2, I still dont know what element in Java2D helps me draw a single border with gradient, can you please advise?

Comment: I'm working on some funky examples. Performance and rendering issues are non-existent (less than 0.1 sec for ~O(1000) borders).

Comment: Finished editing. Both solutions works very fast, but they give different kinds of borders as you will see.

Comment: thank you very much, this is way more than I expected and absolutely brilliant. I have tried the CompoundBorder solution and love it. I will try the 2nd example and report.

Comment: On Java 7, the 2nd example I am having issues compiling with BorderFactory.createStroke, the 2nd argument LGP and RGP is not found...

Comment: I defined `lgp` in the line `LinearGradientPaint lgp;` so it can't "not be found". What line gives you this error? Is it a compiler error or runtime? FYI, `LinearGradientPaint` and `RadialGradientPaint` were introduced in 1.6 so on 1.7 you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: BTW, you can modify the gradient function in example (1) to make the gradient non-linear like example (2) does. I used a simple y=a*x+b function there but implement whatever you fancy.

Comment: My apologies, a mistyped import caused me compilation issues. This is mind-boggling and brilliant! Come to think of it, I like both the techniques. I like the variegated border. I cannot thank you enough for your help :-), maybe beer or  dinner if you are in the Boston area :-)

Comment: I'd gladly take you on your offer had I been anywhere close to Boston. In the meantime, relish upon the free-of-charge and unconstrained information sharing available here. Seriously though, questions of the sort "please make me a___" are way more fun than "find my bug in this" and yours had me painting nice picture all over so I consider myself at a positive gain from this one (also I probably will want to add some of those generally useful functions to my utils).